# Name change and work visa

Tags: visas, paperwork, work

I'm a flight attendant. I got my work visa and my regular travel visa when I was hired. My divorce was not final at the time.

I would like to change my name in my passport. Will this affect my work visa and regular visa? Would I have to apply for a new visa if I apply for a new passport that will contain my new married name?

Comment: Which country issued your visa?

Comment: Did you have to give a valid passport number and information when you applied for the visa? If you did, then changing it means you'll have to ask for a new visa.
Generally speaking, the information on your passport and on your visa should be the same. You could run into trouble if your passport shows a different name than the one on your visa.
That being said, we need more specific info in order to give specific answers. What country is the passport from? Which country issued your visas? Any other useful information that comes to mind might help

Comment: Your employer almost certainly knows the answer to this.